# Two Code Segments need to be above one another to work

Tags: python, tkinter

These two code segments both needs to be above each other to work

```
for i in range(3):
  **def update_btn_text(i):
    btn.configure(bg= color3)
  btn=Button(root,text=box_word,command=update_btn_text(i)**)
  btn.grid(row=x,column=y)
  y+=1
```

Had tried swapping the positions, however it still ended in error(btn not defined or update_btn_text(i) not defined)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Provide sufficient code to reproduce it, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I wonder why you pass `i` to `update_btn_text()`. `i` is not used inside the function. Also `command=update_btn_text(i)` will execute the function *immediately*, you need lambda instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`command=update_btn_text(i)` will execute `update_btn_text(i)` *immediately* and at that time `btn` is not created yet. That's why you got *"NameError: name 'btn' is not defined"*.

Also I wonder why you pass `i` to `update_btn_text()` because `i` is never used inside the function.

You need to use `lambda` with an argument having default value `btn` instead after `btn` is created:

```py
for i in range(3):
  btn = Button(root, text=box_word)
  btn.grid(row=x, column=y)
  # use lambda with argument having default value
  btn.config(command=lambda btn=btn: btn.configure(bg=color3))
  y += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `functools.partial` to provide a function that calls `update_btn_text` with the given parameter:

```py
from functools import partial
# ...
btn = Button(root, text=box_word, command=partial(update_btn_text, i))
```

Comment: I don't see why you need to pass `i` at all when you don't use it though.